# How to convert an mkv file with hevc encoding to mkv with avc

Tags: encoding, file-formats, dvd, mkv

I have some mkv files with a hevc encoding which is not allowing me to burn to disc in covertxtodvd as it shows no video track as the encoding isn't supported, i was wondering if it was possible to convert the files encoding into avc encoding whilst keeping embedded subtitles and the same mkv format.
Thank you for reading,
Nick W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg, a command-line tool, can do this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy -c:s copy -fflags +genpts output.mkv
```

Adjust the CRF for larger or smaller size (lower number produces better quality but larger size)

Download ffmpeg (32-bit static version) from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).

Comment: thank you, i was also wondering if there is a command like this that allows me to keep dual audio streams?

Comment: If the source has dual audio streams, then the above command will keep them both.